Confused about a property of quantum registers
I'm trying to understand quantum registers. At present, I understand that a quantum register composed of $m$ qubits is a superposition of $2^m$ basic states, and is represented as a vector $\boldsymbol{v} = \langle \boldsymbol{v}_{0^m}, \boldsymbol{v}_{0^{m-1}1}, ..., \boldsymbol{v}_{1^m} \rangle \in \mathbb{C}^{2^m}$. That is, if $\boldsymbol{v}_{b(i)}$ is the vector $\boldsymbol{v}_{b(i)}$ in the definition of $\boldsymbol{v}$ (i.e.  $\boldsymbol{v} = \langle ..., \boldsymbol{v}_{b(i)}, ...\rangle$), then $b(i)$, the index of $\boldsymbol{v}_{b(i)}$, is the binary representation of the integer $i$, and $|b(i) \rangle$ is the $i$th basic state of the quantum register. The text I'm reading says that $v$ is such that $\Sigma_x |\boldsymbol{v}_x|^2 = 1$. I'd like to know whether I'm correct in reading $|\boldsymbol{v}_x|$ as the magnitude of the vector $\boldsymbol{v}_x$.

I don't understand the definition of $b(i)$.  You define $b(i)$ in terms of $b(i)$, which seems circular.

Please don't use "Edit: (more stuff)".  Instead, revise the question to read well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.  Define concepts in the order that the reader experience them.  I don't know what "subvector" means.

What do you mean by "magnitude of $v_x$"? When you have several entangled qubits, you'll no longer able to speak about individual qubits without measurements or disentanglement.
